# How to remove an array object item in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is my code

```
var array = [{ id: 1,  name: 'test' }, { id: 2,  name: 'test2' }];
```

I need above array to be changed like below

```
[{ name: 'test' }, { name: 'test2' }]
```

I tried with delete

```
array.forEach(function(arr, i) {
    delete array[i].id;
});
console.log(array);
```

Outputs as

```
[ { id: 1, name: 'test' },
  { id: 2,  name: 'test2'} ]
```

But it doesn't remove the `id` item. How to remove array object item?

I am using this in node **v0.8**.

Comment: Seem to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/fPJ2u/ (?) Tested in FF and Chrome. No id in my console.

Comment: It seems to be working fine in firebug.

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware It's not in client side, but in server side with node **v0.8**.

Comment: I tested your exact code above in node `v0.8.14` and I'm seeing the correct behaviour, i.e. the id element is gone. Apologies if I'm asking the obvious, but is the code above the code that you're actually running?

Comment: I've just tried your code on the Node 0.10.12 command line, and I get your required output from `console.log(array)`, i.e. `[{ name: 'test' }, { name: 'test2' }]`. I'd be surprised if the native array object's behaviour had been changed between these two versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` property *is* deleted, as can be demonstrated by:

```
for (var l in array[0]) {
    if (array[0].hasOwnProperty(l)) {
        console.log(array[0][l]);
    }
}
```

See [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/5KwBV/)

Screenshot of `node.js` output:

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [nicon.nl](http://testbed.nicon.nl/dump/nodejsdelx.png))</sub>

Comment: I am using this in node, where `id` is not deleting.

Comment: See the screenshot of node output.

Comment: What does it means? I didn't get u... :)

Comment: It is your code followed by a loop to check the properties of the first object of the `array` variable ran through the node.exe interpreter. The top shows the code, the bottom half the result. It only shows `test`, which is the value of the only (own) property of object contained by `array[0]`, so the `id` property is removed.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I don't know how it happens to be returning id after deleting it. I just started with fresh copy and it does work great today...

Answer (score 0):

Hm, here is your code with jQuery 1.9.1 and it works good: http://jsfiddle.net/8GVQ9/

```
var array = [{ id: 1,  name: 'test' }, { id: 2,  name: 'test2' }];
array.forEach(function(arr, i) {
    delete array[i].id;
});
console.log(array);
```

By the way, you would like to delete 'property' Id from objects in array- that's better to understand you.

Comment: I am using this in server with node v0.8, where id is not deleting.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the array and build the new version then replace it.

```
var array = [{ id: 1,  name: 'test' }, { id: 2,  name: 'test2' }];    
var tempArray = []; 
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        tempArray.push({name : array[i].name});
    }
    array = tempArray;
```

Comment: I am looking for solution without using a external temp Array.